# Как из функции при нажатии кнопки Ok вызвать открытие ContentView?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Есть такая функция:

```
func didFinishConfirmation(paymentMethodType: YooKassaPayments.PaymentMethodType) { 
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(
            title: "Confirmation",
            message: "успешно",
            preferredStyle: .alert
            
        )
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
        alertController.addAction(action)
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
        
    }
    
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку Ok при появлении предупреждения открывался ContentView() в SwiftUI?

Answer (score 1):

У [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertaction/1620097-init) есть handler,
то есть вам нужно реализовать так

```swift
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in 
// здесь открытие экрана
}
```

для открытия экрана SwiftUI из UIKit нужно использовать [UIHostingController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingcontroller):

```swift
let contentView = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

код полностью:

```swift
func didFinishConfirmation(paymentMethodType: YooKassaPayments.PaymentMethodType) { 
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(
            title: "Confirmation",
            message: "успешно",
            preferredStyle: .alert
            
        )
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in 
            let contentView = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
            self.present(contentView, animated: true)
        }
        alertController.addAction(action)
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
}
```